# could not use find to get specific array element that satisfy my function

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

so I have a selector that contains multiple options and below that I have a paragraph the content of which would change in accordance to the selected option in the select menu. I used find method to loop through the array and return the element(which is an object) that satisfy find function. however there is a problem with find method that I could not figure out.

`````js
'use strict';

{
  function fetchJSON(url, cb) {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url);
    xhr.responseType = 'json';
    xhr.onload = () => {
      if (xhr.status < 400) {
        cb(null, xhr.response);
      } else {
        cb(new Error(`Network error: ${xhr.status} - ${xhr.statusText}`));
      }
    };
    xhr.onerror = () => cb(new Error('Network request failed'));
    xhr.send();
  }

  function createAndAppend(name, parent, options = {}) {
    const elem = document.createElement(name);
    parent.appendChild(elem);
    Object.keys(options).forEach(key => {
      const value = options[key];
      if (key === 'text') {
        elem.textContent = value;
      } else {
        elem.setAttribute(key, value);
      }
    });
    return elem;
  }

  function createLI(root, sel, options = []) {
    const select = document.createElement(sel);

    root.appendChild(select);
    select.innerHTML = options.sort().map(repo => `<option value="${repo.id}">${repo.name}</option>`).join('\n');
 select.addEventListener("change", function () {
      const chosenRepoId = this.value;
      const selectedRepo = options.find(repo => repo.id === chosenRepoId);


      document.getElementById('repoInfo').innerHTML = selectedRepo.description;
    });
  }

  function main(url) {
    fetchJSON(url, (err, data) => {
      const root = document.getElementById('root');
      if (err) {
        createAndAppend('div', root, { text: err.message, class: 'alert-error' });
      } else {
        // createAndAppend('pre', root, { text: JSON.stringify(data, null, 2) });
        createLI(root, 'select', data);
      }
    });
  }

  const HYF_REPOS_URL = 'https://api.github.com/orgs/HackYourFuture/repos?per_page=100';

  window.onload = () => main(HYF_REPOS_URL);
}

````js
`````

Comment: `options = []` you define it allways as empty array in the parameters, so .. what it should find in an empty array?
do `options = options || [];` in the function

Comment: it definitely worked here: 
select.innerHTML = options.sort().map(repo => `<option value="${repo.id}">${repo.name}</option>`).join('\n');

Comment: @RenéDatenschutz  That is the syntax for an optional paramater, ie one that is 'autofilled' if not provided.

Comment: @mynameblabla  Don't you have to do `selectedIndex` to get the value you want? Can you be a little more verbose about what problem you have - is there a specific error, or just "doesn't do anything".

Comment: const selectedRepo = options.find(repo => repo.id === chosenRepoId); 

the value of selectedRepo is undefined

Answer (score 0):

`this.value` returns string.

In the comparison - `const selectedRepo = options.find(repo => repo.id === chosenRepoId);`

you are using `strict equality` operator and your `chosenRepoId` is numeric. So, first convert the selected value to number (use `+` or `parseInt`).

```
const chosenRepoId = +this.value; 
const selectedRepo = options.find(repo => repo.id === chosenRepoId);
```

Comment: randomsoul thanks a lot it worked. 

why does this.value return a string when the repo.id is a numeric value

Comment: @mynameblabla - Your `repo.id` is integer, but `chosenRepoId` is `string`. `value` property returns `string` type. See - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement. If the answer solves the problem, please mark it as accepted to indicate that the problem has been resolved.